# Get response status code of cross domain iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have a iframe on my website which points to 3rd party page (i.e. Not on my domain and I don't have any control on their server).

I want to be able to just check if their website is being loaded properly inside the iframe or not. There can be cases where -

- it gets blocked by some firewall
- their service is down or something.

So that I can show a proper error message inside the iframe in that case. I was hoping that I can find out the iframe's response status code somehow. How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Did you try an `AJAX` request to load the data into a `div` instead of an `iframe`?

Comment: You mean an AJAX request to the 3rd party page?

Comment: `$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});`

Comment: What is the use of loading ajax/test.html. The page I am talking about is on another domain and will be restricted by same origin policy.

Comment: Put your URL to the other domain in place of "ajax/test.html".

Comment: Are you aware of same origin policy? I cannot access a.com from b.com using ajax.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
<script>
function checkIframeLoaded() {
    // Get a handle to the iframe element
     iframe = document.getElementById('your_iframe');

    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

    // Check if loading is complete
    if (  iframeDoc.readyState  == 'complete' ) {

        iframe.contentWindow.onload = function(){
            alert("I am loaded");
        };

        // The loading is complete, call the function we want executed once the iframe is loaded
        afterLoading();
        return;
    } 

    // If we are here, it is not loaded. Set things up so we check   the status again in 100 milliseconds
    window.setTimeout('checkIframeLoaded();', 100);
}

function afterLoading(){
    alert("I am here");
}
</script>

<body onload="checkIframeLoaded();">
```

Comment: I doubt you'd be able to get the `.contentDocument` on the iframe, due to the same origin restriction.